# WaitForMultipleObjects failing c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, concurrent-programming

I am currently writing a program that will run mulitple programs in groups all at once and others on their own.

`if( WAIT_FAILED == WaitForMultipleObjects(numberOfProgramsRan, &information[i].hProcess, TRUE, INFINITE) ) {
            wcerr << L"Failure waiting for process" << endl;
        }`

`numberOfProgramsRan` is the number of programs that i ran in my loop. 
`&information[i]` is a `vector` holding my process information from the create process

When i create the process in a for loop my program will wait if there are two or less processes being created (so two programs being passed in to run) before it runs my next processes.
 If create more than two processes (or pass in more than two programs in my vector) my `WaitForMultipleObjects` it fails.

If i need to futher explain my issue please let me know.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you looked at the result of `GetLastError()`?

Comment: I would not expect `&information[i].hProcess` to be correct. Can you show us the declaration of `information`?

Comment: PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0}; 
information.push_back(pi);

then i use information[i] insead pi in the create process

Comment: @Johnston If that's the case, numberOfProgramsRan should only ever be 1, as there will only be one information[i].hProcess

Comment: @nos i loop it to run on all of the process in the vector

Comment: You're passing it a pointer to the first process's handle. How do you expect it to find a pointer to the second process's handle?

Comment: I ended up loading my vector information into an array and then placing that array in the wait for multiple instead of &information[i]. I also nolonger loop the wait for multiple as as i realized was kinda pointless. Thanks for the help and i wish i could pick more than one right answer since you all gave helpful info. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only wait on a single process (index i) you should use WaitForSingleObject.  If you're waiting on multiple processes you need to pass in an array of handles as others have said - not a pointer into PROCESS_INFORMATION.
If you insist on using WaitFoRmultipleObjects for a single object use:

```
WaitForMultipleObjects(1, &information[i].hProcess, TRUE, INFINITE)
```

If you use anything other than 1 then look at the definition of PROCESS_INFORMATION:

```
typedef struct _PROCESS_INFORMATION {
  HANDLE hProcess;
  HANDLE hThread;
  DWORD  dwProcessId;
  DWORD  dwThreadId;
} PROCESS_INFORMATION, *LPPROCESS_INFORMATION;
```

The following dwProcessId and dwThreadID will then be incorrectly treated as handles your call will not work as expected.

Something like:

```
HANDLE hProcess[MAX_PROCESSES];
for(int i=0; i<numberOfProgramsRan; i++)
{
  hProcess[i] = information[i].hProcess;
}
WaitForMultipleObjects(numberOfProgramsRan, hProcess, TRUE, INFINITE);
```

Will wait on all your processes.

Comment: `&hProcess[0]`?  Really?  Just say `hProcess`.

Comment: Good explanation of why 2 appears to work... because it waits on both the process and the thread.

Answer (score 3):

That `&information[i].hProcess` should be pointer to first element of array of `HANDLE`s that contains `numberOfProgramsRan` elements. By your description it does not sound like to be the case, so i don't know how you imagine that it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are passing in a pointer to an array of HANDLEs (see the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). I don't know what `information[i].hProcess` is but it looks like a single HANDLE member contained within a structure/class. Although if it was a single HANDLE I would expect it to only work with 1 process and not 2 as you mention.

Showing the definition of `information` and how you are initializing/creating the processes here may help as well as reducing the code to a minimum size that still reproduces the issue. Also details on "it fails" may help (error/exception message, what happens, etc...).